# Django - Dynamic form with multiple choice field

Tags: django, forms, dynamic

I'm looking for a snippet which permits to generate django forms dynamically... with multiple choices fields.

I've found a snippet about that on this [link](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/714/).

But even if a guy says what we need to do to get the snippet working with multiple choices field, it doesn't for me!

I'm a newbie on django and on python language so I hope you could help me!
I hope i've been 'readable' and sorry about my poor english.

Thank you
Victor

Comment: Don't say it doesn't work, explain how it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 good blog posts on this

- one by James Bennett: http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/nov/09/dynamic-forms/
- another by Django-creator Jacob Kaplan-Moss: http://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/

Comment: Great! The first link helped me to resolve my problems. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
def create_form():
    class DynamicForm(forms.Form):
        pass

    # Add dynamic fields to form class
    field = forms.fields.ChoiceField(label='test', choices=((0, '0'), (1, '1')))
    DynamicForm.base_fields['field_name'] = field


    return DynamicForm()
```